# Getting Key error while accessing dictionary element on key and not on index

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, keyerror

I have written  a below function to find the pair in a list whose sum is equal to the target:

```
def twoSum(nums, target):
    hash={}
    for i in nums:
        if i in hash.keys():
            continue
        hash[i]=0
    print(hash)
    for i in range(len(nums)):
        temp=target-nums[i]
        if (hash[temp]==1):
            return (nums.index(temp),i)
        else:
            hash[nums[i]]=1
            print(hash)
```

I have passed nums=[3,2,3] and target=6.
While executing this code, I'm getting the below error:

```
{3: 0, 2: 0}
{3: 1, 2: 0}
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "xyz\#1_two_sum.py", line 18, in <module>
print(twoSum(nums,target))
File "xyz\#1_two_sum.py", line 10, in twoSum
if (hash[temp]==1):
KeyError: 4
```

I want to know where I'm making mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your code:

```
def twoSum(nums, target):
    hash={}
    for i in nums:
        if i in hash.keys():
            continue
        hash[i]=0
    print(hash) # lineA
    for i in range(len(nums)): # lineB
        temp=target-nums[i]
        if (hash[temp]==1): # lineC
            return (nums.index(temp),i)
        else: # lineD
            hash[nums[i]]=1
            print(hash)
```

It executes as follows:

1. At `lineA`, the `hash` is `{3: 0, 2: 0}`
2. Then loop starts at `lineB`, the first loop, `i is 0`, so `temp` is `6-3`, that is `3`, and `hash[3]` is `0`, not equal `1`, so goto `lineD`
3. Begin the loop again at `lineB`, the second loop, `i is 1`, so `temp` is `6-2`, that is `4`, then in `lineC` it execute `if hash[4]==1)`, give you error:

> if (hash[temp]==1):
>
> KeyError: 4

In fact, I don't quite understand your logic to get the pair, see next function which could achieve your aims, just FYI:

**test.py:**

```
def find_pair(nums, target):
    print(list(set([(v, target-v) for i, v in enumerate(nums) if target-v in nums[i+1:]])))

# some tests which different inputs
find_pair([3, 2, 3], 6)
find_pair([3, 2, 1], 6)
find_pair([3, 2, 4, 1, 5], 6)
find_pair([3, 2, 4, 1, 5, 3], 6)
find_pair([-1, 7, 5, 3], 6)
```

Just execute it, the output is next which find all pairs:

> [(3, 3)]
>
> []
>
> [(1, 5), (2, 4)]
>
> [(1, 5), (3, 3), (2, 4)]
>
> [(-1, 7)]

Comment: Thank you. I got your point. Instead, I could have taken a list having values 0 initially and change it to 1 when we find an element in the given array.